# About RTTI definition on wikipedia

Tags: c++, rtti

I was going through the example of RTTI here on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information).

I am confused about this part

> abc *abc_pointer = new xyz();

If abc_pointer is being made to point to a xyz object wouldnt it be obvious that that it will get identified.I mean what is the use of comparing

xyz_pointer != NULL

later on and RTTI in general then? Am I missing something here?

Comment: It's a lot more general than that. `abc` could be the base class of many different classes, and during runtime, you might not necessarily know what type of object `abc_pointer` refers to (because it can point to objects of any descendant class of `abc`). RTTI allows you to use `dynamic_cast<T>` (which is actually RTTI) to determine what the real type of the object pointed-to is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The important bit is when they do:

```
xyz_pointer = dynamic_cast<xyz*>(abc_pointer);
```

Later on to cast it back to an `xyz`. Not all `abc`s will be `xyz`s, even though all `xyz`s are `abc`s. Here the `dynamic_cast` says "if it is one of these then cast it, otherwise stop and give me `NULL` instead of doing bad things". `dynamic_cast` is using RTTI for you.

In the toy example you can clearly tell (and the compiler could even figure it out if it wanted to) that the `abc*` was an `xyz*` too. Imagine the function:

```
void (abc *ptr) {
  if (dynamic_cast<xyz*>(ptr)) {
    //...
  }
  else {
    //...
  }
}
```

In that general instance there's no way to tell if what you're given can be cast to an `xyz` without looking at its type information at runtime, which is exactly what `dynamic_cast` does.

Note that had you used `static_cast<xyz*>(ptr)` the cast would always look to have worked, even in cases where it's not actually legal to do so and most likely lead to undefined behaviour.

It should be noted here though that if you find yourself writing lots of `if (dynamic_cast<...` that might indicate a "code smell" - you should consider refactoring, probably a virtual method would be more appropriate. `dynamic_cast` and RTTI should be a last resort when designing C++.